# which flag outputs minizinc running time

Tags: minizinc

I'm running a minizinc model from the terminal but can't see the running time after the program finishes execution:
how could I see the execution/running time? 
Is there a flag for this?

Comment: I'm not sure it can, the execution time shown in the IDE comes from the IDE itself. But in linux you can use the "time" command, simply by prepending it to the command: `time minizinc mymodel.mzn`.

Comment: Most solvers has a flag -s for statistics. The MiniZinc IDE has the Advanced option "Statistics for solving".

Comment: -s outputs nothing when the model runs smoothly from the terminal. Also I'm not sure the "time" command will be precise enough for programs which run in milliseconds?

Comment: "time" should have a precision of 10 ms or better. However, it will measure total CPU time, including starting the applications, parsing, reading/writing files, etc.